# Cannot cancel writing a comment on the iOS app

Tags: support, ios-app

When I tap to write a comment in the iOS app and then decide to cancel, there seems to be no other way, but to kill the app and start it again.

Only the right plane is active and there is no control or link to escape:

[image: iOS writing a comment]

Is there a way? Or is it a bug?

- App version: 1.6.4
- Device: Unknown (iPad6,11)
- OS version: Version 10.3.1 (build 14E304)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click in your unwanted comment then you should be able to click to the right of that, or swipe the comment field left, to pull out the Discard button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but "*able to click to the right of that*" should rather read "swipe the comment field left".

Comment: A click (as well as a swipe) seems to do it for me.

Comment: Oh, I see, the area where it works is pretty small. Stupid me, there's even a hint on the screenshot I posted.